# Compiling DotNetOpenAuth without checking signed assemblies

Tags: build, dotnetopenauth

If you build from Github source, you get an error on checking signed assemblies.

Is it okay just to change:

```
SignAssembly = false
DelaySign = false
```

in `tools\DotNetOpenAuth.props`?

Just for developing/debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that should be fine.

Be cautious about making changes to and building a security library.  You could think you're making a simple or safe change, but actually be inadvertently undermining a security measure and leave yourself vulnerable.