# Umbraco DotNetOpenAuth log4net

Tags: log4net, umbraco, dotnetopenauth

In an Umbraco v6.1.6 I'm trying to get log messages from DotNetOpenAuth. Umbraco already comes with log4net, version 1.2.11.0 without a public key token. The Umbraco logs work fine, but I see no messages from DotNetOpenAuth. I also tried to add a second log4net.dll assembly, the one signed with the public key 669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, while also keeping the non signed one, but to no avail. Any ideas what could go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same setup and tried all manner of web.config redirects and log4net versions to no avail.  The problem is Umbraco is built with an unsigned version of log4net. You have a few options here:

- Try to get dotnetopenauth to use trace logging.  It will default to this when it can't load log4net.  I had problems determining if the trace logging was actually working or not.
- Build your own version of dotnetopenauth - at least you'll be able to debug.  Follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825065/compiling-dotnetopenauth-from-github-sources)